# Discord High-low command

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, nextcord

I'm working on a high low command for my discord bot but it just doesnt work

When I run it,

I get this error:

```
  File "C:\Users\SHAMAN\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\nextcord\application_command.py", line 863, in invoke_callback_with_hooks
    await self(interaction, *args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\Users\SHAMAN\OneDrive\Cloudy-Main\cloudy.py", line 246, in guess
    guess = await client.wait_for('message', check=check)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.2032.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\asyncio\tasks.py", line 408, in wait_for
    return await fut
  File "C:\Users\SHAMAN\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\nextcord\client.py", line 535, in dispatch
    result = condition(*args)
  File "c:\Users\SHAMAN\OneDrive\Cloudy-Main\cloudy.py", line 244, in check
    return m.author  == ctx.user and m.channel == ctx.message.channel
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'channel'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

nextcord.errors.ApplicationInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'channel'
```

Below is my code

```
@client.slash_command(name="highlow", description="Guess a random number!")
async def guess(ctx, *, maxrange:int=10):
    MAX_GUESSES = 5
    number = random.randint(1, maxrange)
    await ctx.send(f"The highlow game has started.\nPlease guess a number between **1-{maxrange}**!\nYou have **{MAX_GUESSES}** guesses.",)
    def check(m):
        return m.author  == ctx.user and m.channel == ctx.message.channel
    for i in range(MAX_GUESSES):
        guess = await client.wait_for('message', check=check)
        try:
            int(guess.content)
            if guess.content == str(number):
                await ctx.send(f"You guessed correctly! It took you **{i+1} tries.")
            elif guess.content >- str(number):
                await ctx.send(f"Lower!")
            elif guess.content <- str(number):
                await ctx.send(f"Higher!")
        except:
            await ctx.send("That isnt even a number :skull:")
        else:
            await ctx.send(f"You lost! You have ran out of tries.\nYou only get **{MAX_GUESSES} guesses.. Good luck next time!")
```

Any help can be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please include the full traceback error.

Comment: nextcord.errors.ApplicationInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'channel'

Comment: Please include the full traceback error in your original post.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: All right I did that, can you check it now?

Comment: I am only familiar with discord.py and this is nextcord, but according to documentation, `ctx.message` in a slash command will always be `None`. Try `ctx.channel` instead.

Answer (score 0):

first of all, I see you just migrated from discord.py to Nextcord or at least from the Post #TAGS I see that you use nextcord for your bot.

If you want to use slash commands, you need to change **ctx to interaction**, so the final code would **look like this**:

```py
@client.slash_command(name="highlow", description="Guess a random number!")
async def guess(interaction: nextcord.Interaction, *, maxrange: int = 10):
    MAX_GUESSES = 5
    number = random.randint(1, maxrange)
    await interaction.send(f"The highlow game has started.\nPlease guess a number between **1-{maxrange}**!\nYou have **{MAX_GUESSES}** guesses.",)
    def check(m):
        return m.author  == interaction.user and m.channel == interaction.guild.channel
    for i in range(MAX_GUESSES):
        guess = await client.wait_for('message', check=check)
        try:
            int(guess.content)
            if guess.content == str(number):
                await interaction.send(f"You guessed correctly! It took you **{i+1}** tries.")
            elif guess.content >- str(number):
                await interaction.send(f"Lower!")
            elif guess.content <- str(number):
                await interaction.send(f"Higher!")
        except:
            await interaction.send("That isn't even a number :skull:")
        else:
            await interaction.send(f"You lost! You have ran out of tries.\nYou only get **{MAX_GUESSES} guesses.. Good luck next time!")
```